# SEXTANTE Saga-grid normalisation and KBS

Tags: qgis, saga, sextante

I tried to use the saga tool grid normalisation. The result is ok but the KBS has changed. Is this an error?

Comment: Can you add which CRS your layer and project have?

Comment: The layer and project have WGS84.

Comment: Sorry, I can not reproduce the error. I opened a .hgt SRTM file, and ran `Analysis->Sextante toolbox->Saga Calculus-> Grid Normalisation`. Can you compare the content of `Properties -> Metadata`? CRS and extent should stay untouched on both layers.

Comment: Ok, I have detected the problem! One of the shapes that I have converted to a grid was in another projection as I thought (I had no *.prj). Now it works how it should. Thank you!

Comment: @Pimpel Please consider adding a solution and accepting it if you found one. That will allow us to consider this question resolved.